Calculate rolling counts from two different time series columns in pyspark
I have a pyspark dataframe that contains two columns. Arrival and departure. The idea is to calculate the number of departure events that fall within a specified window calculated based on arrival time.
So for example, if an item arrived on 23:00 then I would like to take a window of -12 hours [11:00, 23:00] and calculate the number of items that left within that time interval.
Here is my code to create it. But as you see, it doesn't work since I can do hour aggregation either on arrival_time column or dept_time column.
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("rolling_window_example").getOrCreate()

# Sample data
data = [
    ("2024-05-10 02:00:00", "2024-05-10 21:30:00", 0, 1),
    ("2024-05-12 14:10:00", "2024-05-13 02:00:00", 1, 1),
    ("2024-05-05 03:00:00", "2024-05-14 03:30:00", 2, 2),
    ("2024-05-14 01:32:00", "2024-05-14 23:30:00", 0, 2),
    ("2024-05-14 01:00:00", "2024-05-15 01:30:00", 0, 1)
]

columns = ["dept_time", "arrival_time", "ground_truth_12", "ground_truth_24"]

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df = df.withColumn("dept_timestamp", col("dept_time").cast("timestamp"))
df = df.withColumn("arrival_timestamp", col("arrival_time").cast("timestamp"))
df = df.withColumn("dept_time", col("dept_time").cast("timestamp").cast("long"))
df = df.withColumn("arrival_time", col("arrival_time").cast("timestamp").cast("long"))

# Calculate windows wrt arrival time
window_12 = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("arrival_time").rangeBetween(-12 * 3600, Window.currentRow)
window_24 = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("arrival_time").rangeBetween(-24 * 3600, Window.currentRow)

df_rolling = df \
    .orderBy("dept_time") \
    .withColumn("t_12_count", f.count("dept_time").over(window_12)) \
    .withColumn("t_24_count", f.count("dept_time").over(window_24))
                
# Show results
display(df_rolling)

The output is not as expected:
+----------+------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+----------+
| dept_time|arrival_time|ground_truth_12|ground_truth_24|     dept_timestamp|  arrival_timestamp|t_12_count|t_24_count|
+----------+------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+----------+
|1715306400|  1715376600|              0|              1|2024-05-10 02:00:00|2024-05-10 21:30:00|         1|         1|
|1715523000|  1715565600|              1|              1|2024-05-12 14:10:00|2024-05-13 02:00:00|         1|         1|
|1714878000|  1715657400|              2|              2|2024-05-05 03:00:00|2024-05-14 03:30:00|         1|         1|
|1715650320|  1715729400|              0|              2|2024-05-14 01:32:00|2024-05-14 23:30:00|         1|         2|
|1715648400|  1715736600|              0|              1|2024-05-14 01:00:00|2024-05-15 01:30:00|         2|         3|
+----------+------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+----------+

The expected output can be seen in the columns: ground_truth_12 and ground_truth_24 for 12 hours and 24 hours window respectively.

What is the output you were expecting? Makes it easier to understand what you're looking for if you put the expected output here as well.

ground_truth_12 and ground_truth_24 indicate the output :)

Why are you posting the solution by chatgpt? Post your real data problem. Do the calculations manually. And let know why that calculation is correct according to your requirements.

This is not a solution by chatgpt. This is working by myself.

@MuhammadIrfanAli : I posted a solution. let me know how it works out for you. How long it takes to finish, etc.

@user238607 thanks a lot. I am evaluating the solution and will comment soon.

Here's a clever way to figure out all departures before current rows arrival.
Label the corresponding times with arrival flag i.e. "A" or departure "D"
Now union these two dataframes.
Order these dataframes by time irrespective of label.
Create a window specification which will count all the "D" rows that occur within the window of -12 hours to 0s (current row/time).
Do the above operation only for "A" rows since that's what we care about in the final result.
Similarly for -24 hours window.
Important Note :
There is error in the second row ground truth which I have corrected below.
Following is a working example.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SelfJoinExample").getOrCreate()

## There is error in the second row grount truth which I have corrected below.

data = [
    ("2024-05-10 02:00:00", "2024-05-10 21:30:00", 0, 1),
    ("2024-05-12 12:00:00", "2024-05-13 02:00:00", 0, 1),
    ("2024-05-05 03:00:00", "2024-05-14 03:30:00", 2, 2),
    ("2024-05-14 01:32:00", "2024-05-14 23:30:00", 0, 2),
    ("2024-05-14 01:00:00", "2024-05-15 01:30:00", 0, 1)
]

columns = ["departure_time", "arrival_time", "ground_truth_12", "ground_truth_24"]

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df = df.withColumn("departure_timestamp", col("departure_time").cast("timestamp")).drop("departure_time")
df = df.withColumn("arrival_timestamp", col("arrival_time").cast("timestamp")).drop("arrival_time")
df = df.withColumn("mono_id", monotonically_increasing_id())
df = df.withColumn("arrival_label", array(col("arrival_timestamp"), lit("A"), col("mono_id")))
df = df.withColumn("dept_label", array(col("departure_timestamp"), lit("D"), col("mono_id")))

df_arrival = df.select(col("arrival_label").alias("common_name"))
df_dept = df.select(col("dept_label").alias("common_name"))

df_union = df_arrival.union(df_dept)

df_union = df_union.orderBy(col("common_name")[0])
df_union.show(n=1000, truncate=False)


df_mid = df_union.withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp(df_union["common_name"][0]))
df_mid = df_mid.withColumn("long_ts", col("timestamp").cast("long"))
df_mid = df_mid.withColumn("type", df_union["common_name"][1])
df_mid = df_mid.withColumn("value", df_union["common_name"][2].cast(LongType()))
df_mid = df_mid.drop("common_name")
df_mid = df_mid.withColumn("dept_flag", when(col("type") == "D", 1).otherwise(0))

df_mid.show(truncate=False)


windowSpec12 = Window.orderBy("long_ts").rangeBetween(-12 * 3600, 0)
windowSpec24 = Window.orderBy("long_ts").rangeBetween(-24 * 3600, 0)



df_int = df_mid.withColumn("calc_t12",  when(col("type") == "A", sum("dept_flag").over(windowSpec12)).otherwise(None))
df_int = df_int.withColumn("calc_t24",  when(col("type") == "A", sum("dept_flag").over(windowSpec24)).otherwise(None))

df_int.show(n=1000, truncate=False)

df_crosscheck = df.join(df_int, on=[col("type") == "A", col("mono_id") == col("value")], how="inner")

print("Final Result")
df_crosscheck.select("ground_truth_12", "ground_truth_24", "calc_t12", "calc_t24").show(n=1000, truncate=False)

Final cross check dataframe :
+---------------+---------------+--------+--------+
|ground_truth_12|ground_truth_24|calc_t12|calc_t24|
+---------------+---------------+--------+--------+
|0              |1              |0       |1       |
|0              |1              |0       |1       |
|2              |2              |2       |2       |
|0              |2              |0       |2       |
|0              |1              |0       |1       |
+---------------+---------------+--------+--------+

Full Output Below :
+--------------------------------------+
|common_name                           |
+--------------------------------------+
|[2024-05-05 03:00:00, D, 94489280512] |
|[2024-05-10 02:00:00, D, 25769803776] |
|[2024-05-10 21:30:00, A, 25769803776] |
|[2024-05-12 12:00:00, D, 60129542144] |
|[2024-05-13 02:00:00, A, 60129542144] |
|[2024-05-14 01:00:00, D, 163208757248]|
|[2024-05-14 01:32:00, D, 128849018880]|
|[2024-05-14 03:30:00, A, 94489280512] |
|[2024-05-14 23:30:00, A, 128849018880]|
|[2024-05-15 01:30:00, A, 163208757248]|
+--------------------------------------+

+-------------------+----------+----+------------+---------+
|timestamp          |long_ts   |type|value       |dept_flag|
+-------------------+----------+----+------------+---------+
|2024-05-05 03:00:00|1714858200|D   |94489280512 |1        |
|2024-05-10 02:00:00|1715286600|D   |25769803776 |1        |
|2024-05-10 21:30:00|1715356800|A   |25769803776 |0        |
|2024-05-12 12:00:00|1715495400|D   |60129542144 |1        |
|2024-05-13 02:00:00|1715545800|A   |60129542144 |0        |
|2024-05-14 01:00:00|1715628600|D   |163208757248|1        |
|2024-05-14 01:32:00|1715630520|D   |128849018880|1        |
|2024-05-14 03:30:00|1715637600|A   |94489280512 |0        |
|2024-05-14 23:30:00|1715709600|A   |128849018880|0        |
|2024-05-15 01:30:00|1715716800|A   |163208757248|0        |
+-------------------+----------+----+------------+---------+

+-------------------+----------+----+------------+---------+--------+--------+
|timestamp          |long_ts   |type|value       |dept_flag|calc_t12|calc_t24|
+-------------------+----------+----+------------+---------+--------+--------+
|2024-05-05 03:00:00|1714858200|D   |94489280512 |1        |NULL    |NULL    |
|2024-05-10 02:00:00|1715286600|D   |25769803776 |1        |NULL    |NULL    |
|2024-05-10 21:30:00|1715356800|A   |25769803776 |0        |0       |1       |
|2024-05-12 12:00:00|1715495400|D   |60129542144 |1        |NULL    |NULL    |
|2024-05-13 02:00:00|1715545800|A   |60129542144 |0        |0       |1       |
|2024-05-14 01:00:00|1715628600|D   |163208757248|1        |NULL    |NULL    |
|2024-05-14 01:32:00|1715630520|D   |128849018880|1        |NULL    |NULL    |
|2024-05-14 03:30:00|1715637600|A   |94489280512 |0        |2       |2       |
|2024-05-14 23:30:00|1715709600|A   |128849018880|0        |0       |2       |
|2024-05-15 01:30:00|1715716800|A   |163208757248|0        |0       |1       |
+-------------------+----------+----+------------+---------+--------+--------+

+---------------+---------------+--------+--------+
|ground_truth_12|ground_truth_24|calc_t12|calc_t24|
+---------------+---------------+--------+--------+
|0              |1              |0       |1       |
|0              |1              |0       |1       |
|2              |2              |2       |2       |
|0              |2              |0       |2       |
|0              |1              |0       |1       |
+---------------+---------------+--------+--------+


This works well for 30M rows that I tested. The program takes around 2.5-4.5 minutes to complete .

If you need to do this for different ids or groups. you can partition accordingly and it will be even faster on the cluster. I assume you left out the id to simplify the problem.
